# Want to run only one if Condition

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement

What if my `screen width < 1200` then only this `alert('1200')` alert is shown and when my `screen width < 640` then only this `alert('640')` alert is shown. I need to do this without the use of `else` block.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1u3d6xb/)

```js
if ($(window).width() < 1200) {
  alert('1200');
}
if ($(window).width() < 640) {
  alert('640');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try to look at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp `if else statement`

Comment: Here's a better reference on `else if` that W3ClownSchools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: i dont want to use 'else' that's the problem.

Comment: When screen width less then < 640 then functionality of  ' < 1200 ' should works that i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if/else if`. That way only the first matching branch will be followed. Note that for the logic to work successfully in this case you'd need to reverse the order of your conditions. Try this:

```js
if ($(window).width() < 640) {
  alert('640');
} else if ($(window).width() < 1200) {
  alert('1200');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As a side note, detecting the browser width is normally a sign that you're amending the UI for different resolutions. If that's the case you can achieve the same thing in a *much* better way by using CSS media queries.

Comment: In which case, will it go in `else if` condition?

Comment: It will always go in `if` loop, I don't think `else if` will ever get executed.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you're saying. Updated the answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you have to check 640 condition. Because if the width is `300 px` 1200 alert will be shown not 640 alert.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if/else if` instead of multiple `if`, and you have to change the order of your conditions:

```
if ($(window).width() < 640) {
  alert('640');
}
else if ($(window).width() < 1200) {
  alert('1200');
}
```